# What type of 18650 terminal is this?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

Not an electrical engineer, just a hobbyist. But thought this might be the best place to come with my question.

I bought a bike light that uses a single 18650 cell for power, thinking it would work with standard cells. Little did I know, they use a different 18650 configuration than I'm used to. It has concentric positive and negative terminals on the one end, with a non-conductive material on the other side of the wrap. Other than that, it seems like a basic protected Samsung 2600 mAh cell (according to the documentation). Of course, the company way overcharges (no pun intended) for their own replacement batteries.

Just trying to figure out if there's anywhere I can buy 18650s with these same-side terminals, or even just by the terminal connectors and re-wrap some cells myself. I've looked in the usual places (Mouser, battery space, etc.), but it would help if I knew what these are called so I can search for them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations of products to purchase, and questions on the usage of products are both off topic here.  Given your cell shows a clear contact on the negative end its worth wondering if there's actually a path from there you are missing.  But again, *usage* and *sourcing* questions are off topic; this site is reserved only for questions of original design, supporting theory, and those offering design-equivalent detail, *exclusive* of sourcing questions.

Comment: It looks like a custom-made end by the manufacturer, possibly a custom cell also.  Who knows if they have some exotic circuitry in it - perhaps even serializing the battery to the light.  Anything is possible these days.  You're probably stuck with them.  The good news is, there can't be any fakes.

Answer (score 2):

The end is a double-sided PCB which contains the protection circuitry on the other side.

Typically this would protect against some combination of over-charge, over-discharge and over-current.

Here is a typical circuit from a [Chinese source](https://www.banggood.com/10pcs-1S-3_7V-18650-Lithium-Battery-Protection-Board-2_5A-Li-ion-BMS-with-Overcharge-and-Over-Discharge-Protection-p-1570087.html):

[image]

This is in contrast to unprotected 18650 cells as one might 'harvest' from a laptop battery pack, which rely on circuitry outside the cells for protection.

So your PCB is designed with the terminals on one end, which is not that big a deal if you pick the right end, to make the product more convenient (and lock you into one supplier).